# Moving data from columns in a table to rows by a key field?

Tags: esri-geodatabase

I would like to shift data found in a column to a row by Key field. I have a table, within a geodatabase, set up similar to what's below.

```
KEY_    Value
123     Yellow
123     Blue
456     Red
456     Yellow
789     Green
246     Green
246     Orange
```

I want to create a table that moves the data in the Value field to rows based on the KEY_ field. The result will look like what's below.

```
KEY_    Value001    Value002
123     Yellow      Blue
456     Red         Yellow
789     Green
246     Green       Orange
```

Does anyone have an idea of how this can be done? I tried using the Transpose tool Esri offers but it didn't produce the result I'm looking for. I have basic understanding of Python.

Answer (score 1):

I do this in MS Access. Sort of clunky but it works.

123     Yellow

123     Blue

456     Red

456     Yellow

789     Green

246     Green

246     Orange

Summerize the ID's to a new Table, Uniq

123

456

789

246

Add a field to Uniq, named All_Values
join Uniq to the original data on ID, this is a one_to_many relationship
concatenate all colors per ID

UPDATE uniq INNER JOIN [orig] ON uniq.ID = [orig].ID SET
uniq.all_values = uniq.all_values & "," & [orig].color

Export to a CSV or text file, fix commas
add a Header for Column names

Maybe it will give you some ideas to build on.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I worked with my table in Access a bit this morning but haven't made any progress. Access isn't my strength - if you can offer me more step by step instruction that would be great, otherwise I'm going to speak with the Access expert in my office when he's available.

Answer (score 0):

You might try [PivotTable_management](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000n8000000).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The Pivot Table doesn't produce quite the result I am looking for. There isn't a suitable Pivot Field in my table, I just want the data in Value to move to rows by KEY_ field.